# Excluding a particular IIS website from the web farm environment

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-farm-framework

We have developed a website that uses In-Proc sessions, stores images uploaded from it on a folder inside its own virtual directory, and uses a third party tool that uses server side caching. This setup works just fine in a single server instance.

But the client has a web farm environment. When we deployed this site on client's web farm. Things started failing. Till now -

- we have enabled out-proc session, using SQL state management server
- we specified a machine key in the web.config of the server

But the other two, specially the third party tool, is proving difficult to crack.

Will it be possible to remove this one website from the web farm? excuse me if the question sounds naive but I am not a server administrator and not aware of its nitty-gritties

- Will it work if we just deactivate one of the websites?
- Can we deploy this website on one of the servers in the farm, but keep it outside the web farm's load balancing?

Is there any alternative, other than deploying the website on a completely different server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on what vendor the balanacers are but the network admin should be able to setup a VIP (Virtual IP) that translates only to the once server in question.

That is a simple answer but there are many other variables in the network architecture that would have to be answered to accomplish this.  I suggest you contact the administrator of the load balancers and ask them if you can isolate traffic for the website to the specified server.

Comment: Thanks FrankO, I will talk to the admins. Just wanted some background on what is possible and what I can recommend as a solution to them

Comment: No problem.  Please choose my answer as "the answer" if it meets your needs.